# RDCL report viewing problem in IIS default 80 port

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I am using asp.net mvc 5 Project & used RDLC report  when wwwroot folder put my publish file RDLC report not working in default wbsite port 80.
show error 
Server Error in '/Reports' Application.
The resource cannot be found.
Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.

Requested URL: /Reports/CommonViewer.aspx.

But Create New site and used different port than work perfectly.